# List JSON Array data with float value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

How can I properly list this JSON array using a `foreach` loop? After using `file_get_contents`, `json_decode` and `var_dump` from this API URL:

```
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC,XRP,DASH,XMR,ZEC&tsyms=PHP
```

this is what I get:

```
array(7) {
    ["BTC"]=> array(1) { ["PHP"]=> float(62127.29) }
    ["ETH"]=> array(1) { ["PHP"]=> float(2488.82) }
    ["LTC"]=> array(1) { ["PHP"]=> float(746.77) }
    ["XRP"]=> array(1) { ["PHP"]=> float(1.58) }
    ["DASH"]=> array(1) { ["PHP"]=> float(3559.27) }
    ["XMR"]=> array(1) { ["PHP"]=> float(999.01) }
    ["ZEC"]=> array(1) { ["PHP"]=> float(3455.52) }
}
```

Then I listed the data using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($json as $cc => $value) {
    echo '<br/>'. $cc.' : '. $value;
}
```

I get this:

```
BTC : Array
ETH : Array
LTC : Array
XRP : Array
DASH : Array
XMR : Array
ZEC : Array
```

What should I do to display something like this?

```
BTC : 62,127.29
ETH : 2488.82
LTC : 746.77
XRP : 1.58
DASH : 3559.27
XMR : 999.01
ZEC : 3455.52
```

Comment: In your case it's `echo '<br/>'. $cc.' : '. $value['PHP'];`

Comment: Use `$value['PHP']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $value in your foreach is an array, so you have to use PHP index to access it.

```
foreach($json as $cc => $value) {
   echo '<br/>'. $cc.' : '. $value['PHP'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, you are only missing the part where you access the first value of the $value array.

```
foreach($json as $cc => $value) {
    echo '<br/>'. $cc.' : '. $value[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But $value['PHP'] did the trick. :D I forgot to add the 'PHP'

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($json as $cc => $value) {
   echo '<br/>'. $cc.' : '. $value['PHP'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/781962)

```
<?php
$string='{"BTC":{"PHP":62127.29},"ETH":{"PHP":2486.33},"LTC":{"PHP":748.01},"XRP":{"PHP":1.58},"DASH":{"PHP":3560.51},"XMR":{"PHP":996.52},"ZEC":{"PHP":3448.69}}';

foreach(json_decode($string,true) as $cc => $value) 
{
   echo  $cc.' : '. $value["PHP"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: With or without .PHP_EOL, the result is still the same. :D Thanks Sahil! :) Now it's working. :D

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON property you have an object instead of float value for your properties example: `{"BTC":{"PHP":61127.29}}`, it should be `{"BTC":61127.29}` since you have a json object as value you must get it `$value->PHP` where you define a property of sub object that have a value stored.

Comment: No, check the var_dump output. Apparently it was decoded with `json_decode($data, true)`, so those values are arrays, not objects.